# Write unique rows to CSV with pandas in chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 100 million row csv that I have to read in chunks with pandas like this:

```
df_chunks = pandas.read_csv(
    'my-file.csv.gz',
    sep='\t',
    chunksize=100000,
    compression='gzip')

for df in df_chunks:
    # here I filter some rows and columns and after that
    # I write to a new csv
    filtered_df.to_csv(
        'my_filtered.csv.gz',
        sep=',',
        columns=['id', 'date'],
        compression='gzip',
        mode='a')
```

The data I am trying to write looks like this, is only 2 columns

```
id,date
42517544,2019-06-30
42517544,2019-06-30
42517544,2019-07-01
...
```

Now I can use something like `df.drop_duplicates()` but since I am writing in chunks I could end up eventually with duplicates. Notice the file is big, around 10G, so I need to read and write in chunks.

I would like to find a way to do it with pandas and perhaps a set in memory that doesn't consume too much memory because that is a constraint as well.

What is a good approach for this ?

Comment: If you only need 2 columns from the CSV (instead of the large number of columns), then you could specify the `usecols = ['id', 'date']` parameter in your `pd.read_csv` section. If your CSV file *only* contains `id` and `date` this won't help.

Comment: @HS-nebula: Actually I do that for writing but when reading I need to filter on most of the other columns, will update the question though, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could use a database to do this for you? A sqlite file instead of a csv?

Comment: @piRSquared: it could be anything really, it's a string and it could be empty or a non-date field like 'a123121'

Comment: @piRSquared: I am trying to ultimately write this resulting CSV to Redshift, which doesn't have unique constraints, that is why I need to do it in code.

Comment: How many duplicates are you expecting? Could you keep a running `set()` in memory and use that to filter?

Comment: @Dan I could keep a set in memory yes, I thought it's the best approach but I'm afraid the set will grow to big to keep in memory

Comment: @PepperoniPizza why not just delete the duplicates in redshift then?

Comment: I think your options are: (1) do it in RedShift using SQL (2) keep a running set and use that to filter, i.e. a hash table (3) if you can't keep unique hashes in memory and you can tolerate some error maybe a bloom filter will help you, (4) re-read the output file in chunks for each chunk of your input - this will be O(n^2) nd have a lot of I/O overhead. I think option (1) seems like your best bet.

Comment: you could go through each chunk and group by `date` or `id` and dump out to disk separate files (by either `date` or `id`).  Then read those files individually and drop duplicates on those.  You'll have to append to existing files if subsequent chunks have the same `date` or `id` (whichever you chose to group by).  This Will be O(n) but you will have to go through the data twice.  You won't have to store anything in memory.

Comment: Have you considered using `dask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

1 Million Rows

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
n = 1_000_000
dfout = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.random.randint(1000, size=n),
    'date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=1000), size=n)
})

dfout.to_csv('my-file.csv.gz', compression='gzip', sep='\t', index=False)
```

---

#### Solution

Chunk as you did

```
df_chunks = pd.read_csv(
    'my-file.csv.gz',
    sep='\t',
    chunksize=100000,
    compression='gzip')
```

Write individual files per unique `date`

```
for i, df in enumerate(df_chunks):
    for date, d in df.groupby('date'):
        date = pd.Timestamp(date)
        d.drop_duplicates().to_csv(
            f'{date:%Y%m%d}.csv.gz',
            compression='gzip',
            mode='a',
            index=False,
            header=False
        )
    print(f'\r{i}', end='')
```

Read in each individual date file, `drop_duplicates`, and write back out

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('.')

for i, fh in enumerate(path.glob('[0-9]' * 8 + '.csv.gz')):
    df = pd.read_csv(fh, header=None)
    df.drop_duplicates().to_csv(
        'my_filtered.csv.gz',
        compression='gzip',
        mode='a',
        index=False,
        header=False
    )
    print(f'\r{i}: {fh}', end='')

df = pd.read_csv(
    'my_filtered.csv.gz',
    compression='gzip',
    header=None,
    names=['id', 'date']
)
```

#### Validation

```
assert len(df) == len(dfout) - dfout.duplicated().sum()
assert df.duplicated().sum() == 0
```

Comment: very detailed approach, this is indeed a top solution, will try it out, thanks !